# Preposition use in volunteer

Tags: prepositions, verbs

In the correct use of volunteer should I always use preposition?

Example:

> I volunteered Calculus classes to the first year students of my school

or

> I volunteered for (giving) Calculus classes to the first year students of my school.

The examples above *should* mean "I have willingly offered calculus classes for the first year students of my school"

Comment: Can you give us some context? Is this sentence in a paragraph? What are you discussing?

Comment: @Catija Context added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it, and as @Catija points out additional context is helpful.

> I **volunteered** for *(giving)* Calculus classes.
>   I **volunteered to** give Calculus classes.

has the exact meaning you are looking for.

> volunteer

has the meaning *to give up/out something* without compensation, to do something *willingly*.

> The prisoner **volunteered** the information without being tortured.
>   *the prisoner told the information without being tortured*

So,

> I **volunteered** Calculus classes.

means "you gave up/out Calculus classes", which doesn't really make sense since a "class" is not something you can "*give away*", although you can give away "*teaching*" a class and you can give away your time:

> I **volunteered** my time *(to teach a Calculus class)*.

However, most people will usually understand what you are saying in your first sentence.

Comment: The reason (giving) is in parenthesis is that it's actually ambiguous otherwise... "I volunteered for calculus classes" could easily means "I volunteered to take calculus classes"... which isn't what the OP means. In context, "I volunteered calculus classes" could be just fine... "He told Jane that he was struggling in school. I volunteered calculus classes but he declined"... it's a bit ambiguous whether the speaker would be the one teaching the classes but it may be clearer in context.